TailwindCSS transition doesn't work in react-ts(tsx)
I made sidbar menu and when it is active, I want to display soomthly but it couldn't work
It use TSX file and using tailwindCSS
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = React.useState(true);

  const onToggleSidebar = () => {
    setShowSidebar(!showSidebar);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {showSidebar && (
        <nav
          className={`${
            showSidebar ? "w-64 transition-all" : "w-0"
          } border-2 border-red-600  py-4 px-6   bg-white shadow-xl  flex-row`}
        >
          <div className="h-full flex flex-col justify-between">
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center ">
              <h2 className="font-bold">Henry</h2>
              <p className="text-gray-500">Email</p>
            </div>
       
             

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
  safelist: [
    "transition-all ease-in-out duration-500",
    "transition-all ease-in-out duration-300",
    "transition-all ease-in-out duration-200",
    "transition-all ease-in-out duration-100",
  ],
};

I saw one of solution and tried but it dont work

Have you tried adding the duration-500 className directly on nav? But you must add that class and never delete it as you do with the ternary operator.


I changed code like this, seperate tailwindcss with ternary operator but still dont work
You can also try to manually add the transition type with the className: transition-[width]
